# How can I ensure, to have different workflows for Travis CI for different git branches

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, devops, continuous-deployment

I am setting up a CI pipeline.

I have a script which build docker images.

In travis.yml it's something like this.

```
script
  - bash builddocker.sh
```

I want to be able to use the same script and run in such a way that, it builds images and pushes to a different repository for different branches.

For example, for master, push it to `dev-docker-repository`
for feature branches, push it to `team-test-repository'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you could handle inside your script by giving it the branch in parameter e.g.

```
script:
  - bash builddocker.sh $TRAVIS_BRANCH
```

Otherwise it would also be possible to use [build stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/#conditional-stages) and define different jobs depending on the branch e.g.

```
jobs:
  include:
    - name: master branch
      script: bash builddocker.sh dev-docker-repository
      if: branch = master
    - name: other branches
      script: bash builddocker.sh team-test-repository
      if: branch != master
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!
I really like the build stages defining jobs.

Comment: One more thing.
In my repo, I have 5 different buildimages scripts  ( A, B, C, D, E) where each build a different image and push it to the repository. Now, If I make changes only to A, travis will be triggered and it will build all the images, which is redundant. Can I do something about it? Like place different scripts on different folders and place some hooks on folders.

Comment: @Damanpreet You'll need to add custom logic to be able to only build the image you want e.g. by inspecting the modified files in the commit.